# Replace dot before pattern using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, cut

I can get the two inputs:

1. `67.1.3.0.0.221111.1`, or
2. `89.1.5.0.0.221112`

I want to replace the dot before the date pattern (`221111`) with an underscore.

1. Input `67.1.3.0.0.221111.1`, output `67.1.3.0.0_221111.1`
2. Input `89.1.5.0.0.221112`, output `89.1.5.0.0_221112`

Comment: For this kind of task it is important to know what other data can be in the input, where you don't want any replacement. If you don't have any other six-digit-strings, a simple `sed 's/\.([0-9]{6})/_\1/'` will do.

Comment: Should `0.2211112345` become `0_2211112345` or not? Can 1 line contain multiple occurrences of `67.1.3.0.0.221111.1` and/or `89.1.5.0.0.221112` or not? Should `89.1.5.0.0.221112.221112` become `89.1.5.0.0_221112_221112` or not? etc.... Please [edit] your question to provide sample input/output that demonstrates ALL your requirements and we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Should `89.1.5.0.0.123456` become `89.1.5.0.0_123456` or is it only `.221112` you want to become `_221112`? Should `12.3.4.5.6.221112` become `12.3.4.5.6_221112` or is it only when the string starts with `89.1.5.0.0` that it should be changed? All we can do is guess at your general requirements from just 2 examples of strings being changed, please [edit] your question to state your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` substitution `s/\./_/5` or `s/[.]/_/5` will match the 5th dot on each input line and replace it with an underscore.

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 67.1.3.0.0.221111.1 89.1.5.0.0.221112 | sed 's/\./_/5'
67.1.3.0.0_221111.1
89.1.5.0.0_221112
```

Since the input is specified to be in two forms only, this ignores any interpretation of the input as dates and only relies on the fact that it's the 5th dot in either form of input that needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

With sed you might like to use something like this:

```
myvar="67.1.3.0.0.221111.1"
echo $myvar | sed 's/\.\([0-9]\{6\}\)/_\1/'
67.1.3.0.0_221111.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\.(?=\d{6}(?!\d))/_/g' < your-file
```

Would replace every `.` that is followed by 6 decimal digits themselves not followed by a digit with `_`.

To avoid matching on sequences of digits that can't possibly be `YYMMDD` dates, you can change the `\d{6}` to `\d\d(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])` which would be a good start (still allows 220231 for instance though).